# ReactJS Infinite request loop when using useState

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm starting out my path with front end and I'm encountering some issues when trying to integrate my front end with my backend API.

I know I need to use states but some issues are arising when trying that out, mainly an infinite loop of requests happening.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing

```
const AppLayout = () => {
    const [
        loading, 
        setLoading
    ] = useState(true);

    const [
        userState, 
        setUserState
    ] = useState(null);

    const populateUser = async() =>{
        let profile_data = await UserService.findUser()
        const user = {"name": profile_data["name"]}

        setUserState(user)
        setLoading(false)
    }

    populateUser()

    return(
        <>
        {
            !loading && <h1>{userState.name}</h1>
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? By executing this, I'm getting stuck in a loop of requests to the API.

Edit1: I was not clear in my objective here. The idea for this is simply to show the name of the user. This is being obtained via the `UserService` which interacts with the API.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks You have this FAQ question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `useEffect` hook to handle the async call.

```
const AppLayout = () => {
    const [
        loading, 
        setLoading
    ] = useState(true);

    const [
        userState, 
        setUserState
    ] = useState(null);

    const populateUser = async() =>{
        let profile_data = await UserService.findUser()
        const user = {"name": profile_data["name"]}

        setUserState(user)
        setLoading(false)
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
        await populateUser()
        return () => { ignore: true }
    }, [])
    

    return(
        <>
        {
            !loading && <h1>{userState.name}</h1>
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

This will populate on render of the component. Since you are using functional components you should read about hooks, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) is a good reading.